# Connecting to oracle database with proxy address

Tags: c#, oracle

So I'm trying to connect to an Oracle database using the `Oracle.ManagedDataAccess`-library, where I'm using the following datasource:

```
(DESCRIPTION =(SOURCE_ROUTE = YES)
(ADDRESS_LIST=
(ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(Host = PROXY-OracleConnectionManager)(Port = 1111))
(ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP) (Host = MAIN-DATABASE) (Port = 0000)))
(connect_data= (UR = A)(SERVICE_NAME = SERVICENAME)))
```

I'm also providing a user id and password.

We don't have any control over the database on our end, but as far as I know, they are using a connection manager as the first address, which should route us to the next address in the list if we are authenticated. This works when using this in Oracle SQL Developer but does not work programatically with `Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.`

This is how I build and use the connection string:

```
var connString = new OracleConnectionStringBuilder
            {
                {"User Id", settings.DbUserId},
                {"Password", settings.DbUserPassword},
                {"Data Source", settings.DbDataSource}
            };
OracleConnection conn = new OracleConnection(connectionString.ToString())
conn.Open()
```

When I run this, I get the following error:

> ORA-12537: Network Session: End of file

I suspect that the issue is the `ADDRESS_LIST` and that the routing doesn't work, but I can't say for sure. Anyone able to provide some insight?

Comment: I've had better luck in-lining the TNS in the `Data Source` of the `ConnectionString` instead to using a `ConnectionStringBuilder`

Comment: Do you have an example? When I did `..SERVICENAME)));User ID=ID;Password=Pass;` it didn't verify the password.

Comment: not sure what you mean by "verify the password". You can try something along the lines of `Provider=(Your provider of choice);Data Source=(In-line TNS);User Id=yourUser;Password=pass;Persist Security Info=True;"`

Comment: Getting the same error, but thanks anyway!

Comment: Have you checked http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29847444/odp-net-oracle-manageddataaccess-causes-ora-12537-network-session-end-of-file ?

Comment: Yeah, it didn't solve my problem unfortunately