# Oracle Managed DataAccess causes ORA-12537 Network Session: End of file

Tags: asp.net, oracle, entity-framework-5

I could not create Oracle edmx in my asp.net solution when i use oracle.ManagedData access

Below is the stack trace, Please advice. I have also tried the solutions provided in [ODP.NET Oracle.ManagedDataAccess causes ORA-12537 network session end of file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29847444/odp-net-oracle-manageddataaccess-causes-ora-12537-network-session-end-of-file)

```
[NetworkException (0x30f9): ORA-12537: Network Session: End of file]
   OracleInternal.Network.ReaderStream.Read(OraBuf OB) +564
   OracleInternal.TTC.OraBufReader.GetDataFromNetwork() +378
   OracleInternal.TTC.OraBufReader.Read(Boolean bIgnoreData) +122
   OracleInternal.TTC.MarshallingEngine.UnmarshalUB1(Boolean bIgnoreData) +43
   OracleInternal.TTC.TTCProtocolNegotiation.ReadResponse() +212

[OracleException (0x80004005): ORA-12537: Network Session: End of file]
   OracleInternal.ConnectionPool.PoolManager`3.Get(ConnectionString csWithDiffOrNewPwd, Boolean bGetForApp, String affinityInstanceName, Boolean bForceMatch) +7686
   OracleInternal.ConnectionPool.OraclePoolManager.Get(ConnectionString csWithNewPassword, Boolean bGetForApp, String affinityInstanceName, Boolean bForceMatch) +1178
   OracleInternal.ConnectionPool.OracleConnectionDispenser`3.Get(ConnectionString cs, PM conPM, ConnectionString pmCS, SecureString securedPassword, SecureString securedProxyPassword) +1541
   Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client.OracleConnection.Open() +3739
   System.Data.EntityClient.EntityConnection.OpenStoreConnectionIf(Boolean openCondition, DbConnection storeConnectionToOpen, DbConnection originalConnection, String exceptionCode, String attemptedOperation, Boolean& closeStoreConnectionOnFailure) +44

[EntityException: The underlying provider failed on Open.]
   System.Data.EntityClient.EntityConnection.OpenStoreConnectionIf(Boolean openCondition, DbConnection storeConnectionToOpen, DbConnection originalConnection, String exceptionCode, String attemptedOperation, Boolean& closeStoreConnectionOnFailure) +203
```

Comment: Are you have instal ODAC? And which version are you use? 11.2? I have similar problem with 12c x64 and i solve this problem by reinstal to 11.2 x32.

Comment: Thanks. I have installed ODAC 12c Release 4 (12.1.0.2.4) x32. Do you want me to install a lower version of this package .?

Comment: I use EF 5 with Oracle 11 and ODAC 11.2 work, 12c not.

Comment: Thanks for the info. Can you please confirm are you using Oracle.ManagedDataAccess or oracle.DataAccess.client as provider for database connectivity .?

Comment: I prefer Oracle.ManageDataAccess but in old app i still use Oracle.DataAcces both work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have fixed this by recreating edmx with unmanaged driver instead of managed Driver. Application works perfect. !! used ODAC 12c Release 4.