# ERROR : ORA-12537: Network session: End of File

Tags: oracle, visual-studio-2013, oracle11g

When i tried to test connection with oracle database on visual studio, it hit below error `ORA-12537: Network Session: End of file` . Any ideas how to solve it?

[image]

i saw a lot of posts asked to change the configuration in `sqlnet.ora`, i did too but same error.

[image]

Below is the `listener.ora`
[image]

Below is the `tnsnames.ora`
[image]

May i know which part im wrong? Please give some advices, thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ODP.NET Oracle.ManagedDataAccess causes ORA-12537 network session end of file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29847444/odp-net-oracle-manageddataaccess-causes-ora-12537-network-session-end-of-file)