# How to connect appsheet to oracle autonomous database always free

Tags: oracle, connection, database-connection

Appsheet in principle gives you the option to connect to an oracle database in the cloud, but it only lets you set the parameters of server name, database name, username and password. I tried a lot of options but it always ends up giving me:
Failed to establish connection. Error: ORA-12537: Network Session: End of file

If anyone knows where the problem comes from, I will thank them.

Comment: Have a look at this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29847444/odp-net-oracle-manageddataaccess-causes-ora-12537-network-session-end-of-file and see if your problem is similar to theirs.

Answer (score 1):

That won't work for Autonomous.

Autonomous is secured with a Wallet. You must be able to provide it as part of your connection string. Specifically for SSL, you need to be able to define ssl_server_cert_dn in your JDBC or TNS / EZConnect string.

Comment: Hi, the issue is that Appsheet only offers that connection option to connect to an oracle database in the cloud, it seems very strange to me because I understand the same thing as you.
So I wanted to know if someone had been able to connect from Appsheet and how they had done it.
Thank you very much